# Finding a uniformly continuous function from a non complete space to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $(X, d)$ is not complete. Prove that there exists a uniformly continuous function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that $\inf_{X} f(x) = 0$.

We are guaranteed the existence of a completion of a metric space, so let $(Y, d)$ be the completion of $(X, d)$ with isometry $f:X \rightarrow Y$. Fix $a \epsilon Y\setminus X$, and let $g(x) = d(x, a)$ for any $x \epsilon X$. Clearly, $g$ is is a continuous map (proved this in class) whose codomain is the set of positive real numbers (notice it is nonzero) since a metric is, by definition, always positive except when taking $d(x, x)$. So clearly the greatest lower bound is zero.

Now to show $g$ is uniformly continuous. I just spent the last hour or so typing/writing a bunch of epsilon delta stuff but it wasn't getting me anywhere. I know I need to show $d(x_{1}, x_{2}) < \delta \Rightarrow d(g(x_{1}), g(x_{2})) < \varepsilon$, but I'm unsure how...this is just some scratch work:

For any $\varepsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \varepsilon / 2$. let $x_{1}, x_{2}$ be in $X$, then

$$d(g(x_{1}), g(x_{2})) = d(f(g(x_{1})), f(g(x_{2})))$$
$$\leq d(f(g(x_{1})), y) +  d(y,f(g(x_{2})))$$
for any $y$ in $Y \setminus X$...I'm not sure where I'm going with this...

Comment: Triangle inequality gives you $$|d(a,x_1) - d(a,x_2)| \leq d(x_1,x_2)$$ So just take $\delta = \epsilon$

Comment: So we want to show for all epsilon greater than zero, and for all $x_{1}, x_{2}$ in $X$, $d_{X}(x_{1}, x_{2}) < \delta \Rightarrow d_{\Bbb R}(g(x_{1}), g(x_{2})) < \varepsilon$. Choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Suppose $d_{X}(x_{1}, x_{2}) < \delta$. Then it follows from the triangle inequality that

$|d(x_1, a) - d(a,x_2)| = |d(x_1, a) - d(x_2, a)| = |g(x_1) - g(x_2)| = d_{\Bbb R}(g(x_{1}), g(x_{2})) \leq d(x_1,x_2) < \delta = \varepsilon$

Yea?

Edit: the reason why I say $d_{\Bbb R}(a, b)$ is just because $g$ maps from $X$ to $\Bbb R$.